# Multiple galleries on the same page

Tags: javascript, gallery, slideshow, interrupt

I have these two galleries: https://jsfiddle.net/au254p1q/3/
When i'm on second image and i click "next", the slideshow proceeds on the second gallery (image three). How can i avoid this? I need two separated slideshow to each gallery. Thanks.

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with highslide js, but as I see you are using same instance of hs for two galleries, so it toggles between all images provided. Only difference in your code is html, it doesn't make logical distinction between galleries, only visual. You should make separate instance for second gallery, if it isn't singleton. I guess that you're trying to do some lightbox, try [this](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/). As I see, it make possible to pass instance for different elements. You should pass your data attribute to element you want: `[data-toggle="lightbox"]` for one, `[data-toggle="lightbox-2"]` for second, and this should work. It requires jQuery on the other hand.

Comment: I need precisely the gallery of my example, with its specific zooming and transition effects. Could it be possible to enclose javascript calling into a specific div, so that it works only inside of it and not outside?

Comment: I'm afraid there's only some hacky-way to do that. I'd try to download highslide js, copy and then rename internal function names (in copied one). Sound very bad, but maybe can work :/